# like operator with inner query in MySQL does not work

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT ser_id
FROM services
WHERE name = "office_small"
AND pr_id = (
            SELECT pr_id
            FROM profile
            WHERE pr_name  like ( SELECT sel_profile
                                 FROM customer
                                 WHERE id =443
                                )
              )
```

hi,every one i use upper query in `MySQL` but it returns zero rows but when i use it with in clause it returns correct result so if there any restriction to use like for inner query?
thanks

Comment: Could you show some sample data and the desired output, please?

Comment: Why do you think `IN` and `LIKE` are interchangeable operators?

Comment: The operators `=` and `LIKE` can only work with single, scalar values. So make sure your subqueries do only return single values.

Answer (score 0):

try running the query from the last

```
1.SELECT sel_profile  FROM customer  WHERE id =443 =OUTPUT
2.(SELECT pr_id FROM profile  WHERE pr_name  like =OUTPUT) =OUTPUT2
3.(SELECT ser_id FROM services WHERE name = "office_small" AND pr_id = OUTPUT2) =OUTPUT3
```

if you get correct results then you are right path otherwise there might be issue related to database table

Answer (score 0):

```
1.SELECT sel_profile  FROM customer  WHERE id =443 =OUTPUT
2.(SELECT pr_id FROM profile  WHERE pr_name  like '%OUTPUT%') =OUTPUT2
3.(SELECT ser_id FROM services WHERE name = "office_small" AND pr_id = OUTPUT2) =OUTPUT3
```